# What is the right way to access DAAPs?

Tags: blockchain, mist, dapps, ipfs

I am a newbie and I am a bit confused about the deploying process of the DAPPs, I have some unclear points

- Can I access DAPPs outside Mist browser? Can I access them using Chrome for example?
- Should all the DAPPs use IPFS protocol?
- I saw many tutorials showing DAPPs using IPFS throw HTTP? what is the point of IPFS if I would use HTTP to access it!
- If I will be able to access DAPPs throw HTTP, then the serverless concept will be broken, and I am wondering, How can chrome Handel protocols such as Wishper ?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I access DAPPs outside Mist browser? Can I access them using Chrome for example?

Yes, you can access any dapp through any browser, assuming the client-side of the dapp is hosted at some url. Interacting with the dapp (creating/signing transactions) requires access to a private key manager (usually MetaMask if you are using chrome/brave).

> Should all the DAPPs use IPFS protocol?

I think this really depends on what the dapp does.  It is by no means necessary for all dapps. To my knowledge, IPFS is useful for storing data which is too large/inefficient to store on the Ethereum blockchain.

> I saw many tutorials showing DAPPs using IPFS throw HTTP? what is the point of IPFS if I would use HTTP to access it!

IPFS can be accessed through FUSE and HTTP. The benefits of IPFS are performance, file integrity, censorship resistance, and plenty of others I'm sure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But what is the purpose of Mist browser if I can use any other browser

Comment: Mist browser includes private key management built-in, so you wouldn't need MetaMask