# Is web3 completely decentralized?

Tags: web3js, dapps

I think web3 is not completely decentralized or safe to use.

**Consider the following example**:

I have made a voting [Dapp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decentralized_application) on Ethereum.

- Now my smart contract will be on the Ethereum blockchain and my variable and functional calculation will be evaluated on EVM.
- But still I need to host my website (HTML/JavaScript code) using a web hosting service like Heroku (which will then communicate with the Ethereum blockchain to provide information).
- It is true that a hacker won't be able to edit data (because it is on Ethereum), **but he/she can still hack web hosting service (Heroku), right?**

And if it is hacked my Dapp won't be available to people.
Then why is Ethereum considered as safe to use?

Please someone correct me if I am wrong, or suggest an alternative solution that even website service cannot be hacked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...or suggest an alternative solution that even website service cannot be hacked.

The alternative is the host the front end in a decentralised manner.

This can be achieved using a service such as [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) or [Swarm](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).

Also see:

- [What is Swarm and what is it used for?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/375/what-is-swarm-and-what-is-it-used-for)
- [What is the right way to access DAAPs?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45606/what-is-the-right-way-to-access-daaps)
- [What is the difference between Swarm and IPFS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2138/what-is-the-difference-between-swarm-and-ipfs)

> And if it is hacked my Dapp wont be available to people.

Your contracts will still be accessible by other means, for example by using a proxy such as Infura, or by running a client a locally.

Comment: ok I get it . by the way is there any way to know if a website is IPFS based , for example is https://coinmarketcap.com/ IPFS technology based website?

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure how you'd tell. A basic implementation would require a user to access the site via an URL that included an IPFS gateway (e.g. https://gateway.ipfs.io/ipfs/QmaEBknbGT4bTQiQoe2VNgBJbRfygQGktnaW5TbuKixjYL/), but it's possible to bind this to a domain by playing around with  DNS TEXT records. I don't know enough about DNS look-ups to know how easy it would be to tell if it was IPFS underneath. Perhaps ask this as a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the web hosting phase could be implemented as a part of the file systems built on blockchain as mentioned by Richard above like  [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) or [Swarm](https://swarm-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) and other links on study material for the product.

Having this concern today is valid in this case of Web applications safety and it's centralised management. Once, the technology matures enough to handle tons of HTTP requests to be served from a blockchain as fast as the HTTP Protocol ([Scalability](https://medium.com/@bitrewards/blockchain-scalability-the-issues-and-proposed-solutions-2ec2c7ac98f0) -> better Transactions per second), that is when the completeness in safety and move towards decentralization would be realized.